# Checking usertype in Firebase using swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase

beginner to both swift and Firebase here!  I have a database that looks something like this:

Database
 players
  ref.authdata.uid-for-player-1
  ref.authdata.uid-for-player-2
  ref.authdata.uid-for-player-3
 coaches
  ref.authdata.uid-for-coach-1
  ref.authdata.uid-for-coach-2
  ref.authdata.uid-for-coach-3

One half of my app is built for players, one for coaches.
How do I check if the ref.authData.uid child is under the player or the coach child?  Is my data structured the wrong way?

Also, each uid has more children underneath it which I didn't include in my diagram, containing information about each player/coach. Below is the auth method I'm using for my preliminary build.

```
if ref.authData != nil  {

     print("There is already a user signed in!")
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerLogin", sender: self)

 } else {
     // No user is signed in
 }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tobeisdev has a good answer (I would accept it) and the linked answer would work as well.

I would like to add an alternative as well; since coaches and players are all users why not go with the standard Firebase /users design pattern

```
users
  user_id_0
    type: "player"
    name: "Larry"
    team: "team_id_0"
  user_id_1
    type: "player"
    name: "Biff"
    team: "team_id_0"
  user_id_2
    type: "coach"
    name: "Benny"
    team: "team_id_0"
```

then you could add a teams node

```
teams
  team_id_0
    team_name: "nerds r' us"
    coach: user_id_2
    players:
       user_id_0: true
       user_id_1: true
```

This would enable you to query for a specific coach or player and get their uid as well as know which team that player or coach is part of. You could also get a team and know who the coach and players are.

just a thought.

Comment: This is awesome, this structure works much better for some other things I'll be doing with this database further down the road.  Thanks Jay!  In my last question you mentioned with regard to databases "The flatter the better"; I'm starting to understand how that comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I can share with you some ways to search and check any ref-uid in these parent node, you can use this lines of codes:

```
let REF_BASE = Firebase(url: "https://yourapp.firebaseio.com")

REF_BASE.childByAppendingPath("players").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let key = snap.key as String
            if key == "ref.authdata.uid-for-player-2" {
                print(snap.value as String) // to see its value
            }
        }

    })

REF_BASE.childByAppendingPath("players").childByAppendingPath("ref.authdata.uid-for-player-2").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.value as? String == nil {
            print("in usage")
        }
        else {
            print("free")
        }

    })
```

For more details look at [Jay's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882630/firebase-checking-for-null-value-swift).

Comment: Aaah okay these queries are starting to make sense.  Coming from Parse(R.I.P) the structuring of firebase queries is a new thing for me.

Can you explain what the last chunk of your solution does?  To me it looks like it checks to see if the user's UID exists in players, then if it does performs a player login, and if not performs a coach login without checking "coaches" for that same UID.  Am I right?

Comment: @JoeSloan `if snapshot.value is NSNull {` and `if snapshot.value as? String == nil {` same thing if it's in these blocks, you can check another node to provide your UID exist or not. But It's not in -players- like you said.