# Pausing an observeEventType Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I currently have an observeEventType function, and then a transitionBlock in a my iOS App. Both of them are using the same ref, causing the app to crash at the observeEventType

```
  self.ref.child("data").child("lynes").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value!)
            self.removeAll()

            var data = snapshot.value! as! [String: AnyObject]

            //Code Crashes on the line above

            for (key, value) in data {
                print("\(key) -> \(value["name"]!)")
                    dataArray.append(key)
                    locArray.append(value["location"] as! String)
                nameArray.append(value["name"] as! String)
                totalArray.append(value["total"] as! Int)
            }


            self.configureSearchController()

            print(dataArray)

            self.tableView.reloadData()


            // ...
        })
```

**Error: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10df0f600) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10df0efe8).**

And the transitionBlock which is being called after a button click on the view:

```
self.ref.child("data").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {....
```

Is there any way to pause this event from **continuously listening** for a change in data, and instead, run it after my transition block completes?

Comment: There is no inherent problem with having multiple listeners on the same ref/location. Are you sure that is the cause of the crash? Can you add enough code to show?

Comment: Added. I feel that the code looks a bit dysfunctional and I'm still working on it. My transition block looks confusing, and that's because of this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738144/run-2-transitionblocks-in-swift-firebase

Comment: OK. That leaves the question what crashes about the code. I would also be nice if you could reduce it to only the parts relevant to that crash.

Comment: Updated. Crashing on the snapshot.value line of the observeEventType.

Comment: The exception is pretty explicit. You're getting a null value and hard-cast it to a dictionary. You'll want to check `if snapshot.exists()` or `if snapshot.value is NSNull` before that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882630/firebase-checking-for-null-value-swift

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so what I ended up doing was writing a simple if statement, catching if the null existed.

```
if let data =  snapshot.value! as? [String: AnyObject] {
                for (key, value) in data {
                    print("\(key) -> \(value["name"]!)")
                    dataArray.append(key)
                    locArray.append(value["location"] as! String)
                    nameArray.append(value["name"] as! String)
                    totalArray.append(value["total"] as! Int)
}}
```

It's a workaround when the null error comes up.